# JavaTokenParser Parser gets confused between two types I have created

Tags: regex, parsing, scala, token

This is for a class so I would prefer hints or something to read rather than just the answer unless it is just an obvious mistake.  The parser is getting confused between DATE and VARCHAR I believe it is because they both start with a tick mark (') and end with a tick.  I can not change the syntax it needs to stay this way

```
def atype: Parser[Any] =  "(?i)INTEGER".r | "(?i)REAL".r | "(?i)BOOLEAN".r | "(?i)VARCHAR".r  | "(?i)DATE".r 

def typeDate: Parser[Value] = "'" ~ dayOrMonth ~"/"~dayOrMonth~"/"~year ~ "'" ^^
        {case _ ~ a ~ _ ~ b ~ _ ~ c ~ _ => new typeDate(a,b,c)}

def dayOrMonth: Parser[String]= "([0-9][0-9])".r 

def year:Parser[String] = "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])".r

def stringExpression: Parser[Value] = "'" ~> string <~ "'"  ^^
        {case a => new stringExpression(a)}
def string: Parser[Any] = letters

def letters: Parser[Any] =  """([a-zA-Z])+""" r
```

Comment: In `typeDate` you can use `~>` instead of `~` to skip intermediate symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem string should be defined as

`def string: Parser[Any] = """([a-zA-Z0-9])+""" r`